# PNG image not showing in Eclipse ImageView

Tags: android, eclipse, image

I am using the Eclipse drag 'n drop feature to add a PNG image to my app UI.

When I drag the ImageView widget from the menu into the UI area it asks me to select the image from a list.  I have named the picture image1 and when I select it there is just a placeholder image (a red cube with Aa in).

I have tried re-sizing the image and using different images.  The placeholder image is visible on my UI but nothing I have tried can made the actual picture I have put in my xhdpi folder show up on the screen.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why but when I changed the filename from image1.png to image2.png it worked.

The placeholder image that I kept seeing was listed higher up in the hierarchy as image1-web.png so I wonder if that was taking precedence.